# Reference the output of a calculated column in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive

I have a self-referencing/recursive calculation in Excel that needs to be moved to Hive SQL. Basically the column needs to `SUM` the two values only if the total of the concrete column plus the result from the previous calculation is greater than 0.

The data is as follows, A is the value and B is the expected output:

```
|  A  |  B  |
|-----|-----|
|  -1 |  0  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  -2 |  0  |
|  2  |  2  |
|  2  |  4  |
|  -1 |  3  |
|  2  |  5  |
```

In Excel it would be written in column B as:

```
=MAX(0,B1+A2)
```

The problem in SQL is you need to have the output of the current calculation. I think I've got it sorted in SQL as the following:

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE(A INT, Rn INT)

INSERT INTO @Numbers VALUES (-1,1),(2,2),(-2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(-1,6),(2,7);

WITH lagged AS
(
    SELECT A, 0 AS B, Rn
    FROM @Numbers
    WHERE Rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i.A, 
        CASE WHEN ((i.A + l.B) >= 0) THEN (i.A + l.B)
            ELSE l.B
        END, 
        i.Rn
    FROM @Numbers i INNER JOIN lagged l
    ON i.Rn = l.Rn + 1
)
SELECT *
FROM lagged;
```

But this being Hive, it doesn't support CTEs so I need to dumb the SQL down a touch. Is that possible using LAG/LEAD? My brain is hurting having got this far!

Comment: I believe that this type of calculation requires recursive CTEs or a similar construct.  You can't implement it with analytic functions.  The problem is that the break-points (where the zeros go) are cumulatively data dependent.  You can't just figure them out in advance and then do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that's the kicker. We may just need to do it with a `CURSOR` or in SQL...

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought that it would help to first compute the Sum of all elements until each rank and then fix the values somehow using negative elements.

However, one big negative that would zero the `B` column will carry forward in the sum and will make all following elements negative.

It's as Gordon commented - 0 is max in the calculation `=MAX(0,B1+A2)` depends on the previous location where it happened and it seems to be impossible to compute them in advance analytically.

Comment: Sounds interesting Alex but the negatives should be included in the `SUM` only if the calculation result plus the negative value is greater tahn 0. May be tougher...

Comment: oops, you are correct... let me think if it can still be solved without recursion